# Sending parameters in Jquery via Ajax doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax

I tried very hard but I can't figure out what is wrong. I want to send some parameters via ajax but everytime something is wrong. My code is :

```
    sendInsertValues : function(serviceCode, description, borrowerCoborrower, expiration, premiumValue,comissionValue,maxAge,companyCode) {         
        var callUrl = "http://localhost:9080/XA-UW0-PF/tmInsurance.do?method=add";
        var date = new Date();
        var time = date.getTime();

            $.ajax({            
             type        : "POST",
             url         : callUrl,
             data: "serviceCode=" + serviceCode+
                   "&description="+ description +
                   "&borrowerCoborrower="+ borrowerCoborrower +
                   "&expiration="+ expiration+
                   "&premiumValue="+ premiumValue+
                   "&comissionValue="+comissionValue+
                   "&maxAge="+maxAge+
                   "&companyCode="+companyCode+
                   "&time="+time,                
             success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                       alert("Operation completed.");
                        window.close();
                 },
             error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                 {
                        alert("Operation not completed.");

                 }          
});
```

}

I hope that somebody can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 sendInsertValues : function(serviceCode, description, borrowerCoborrower, expiration, premiumValue,comissionValue,maxAge,companyCode) {         
        var callUrl = "http://localhost:9080/XA-UW0-PF/tmInsurance.do?method=add", data = {
        "serviceCode" :  serviceCode,
        "description":  description,  
        "borrowerCoborrower":  borrowerCoborrower, 
        "expiration":  expiration,
        "premiumValue":  premiumValue, 
        "comissionValue": comissionValue, 
        "maxAge": maxAge, 
        "companyCode": companyCode, 
        "time" : time
        };

return $.post(callUrl, data).done(function(response) {
        alert("Operation completed.");
        window.close();
}).fail(function(error){alert("Operation not completed.");});
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but is still get "Operation not completed."

Comment: I finally succeded. Thank you all guys especially you kayz1. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

data should be like this

```
data:{ "serviceCode":serviceCode,
        "description":description,
        "borrowerCoborrower":borrowerCoborrower,
        "expiration":expiration,
        "premiumValue":premiumValue,
        "comissionValue":comissionValue,
        "maxAge":maxAge,
        "companyCode":companyCode,
         "time":time
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `data` as JSON

```
data:   {
        "serviceCode" :  serviceCode,
        "description":  description,  
        "borrowerCoborrower":  borrowerCoborrower, 
        "expiration":  expiration,
        "premiumValue":  premiumValue, 
        "comissionValue": comissionValue, 
        "maxAge": maxAge, 
        "companyCode": companyCode, 
        "time" : time
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried:

```
data: { 'serviceCode': serviceCode, 'description' ... }
```

Just passing parameters as JSON object.

Comment: Have You got any errors? And one more - remember that You cannot make cross-domain ajax requests in this way. I have this problem and it was difficult to diagnose for first time.